# to find a value within the array in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to search data in an array .How can i search using mysql select command. i wrote the query as

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM client_details WHERE dob IN ({implode(',', $data})");
```

$data is an array of dates .Please Help me for solving this..

Comment: And what is the error message you get?

Comment: so whats the problem ??? where you stuck ????

Comment: Error Number: 1064

Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '})' Ã  la ligne 1

SELECT * FROM client_details WHERE dob IN ({implode(',', 03/03/2015})
error showing like this

Comment: You have to properly escape the string, use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: how can i use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Also, note that dates adhere to a specific format in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
$data =array('0'=>'2015-01-23','1'=>'2015-01-22','2'=>'2015-01-21');
$tmp = implode('","', $data);
$tmp ='"'.$tmp.'"';
$sql= 'SELECT * FROM client_details WHERE dob IN ('.$tmp.')';
echo $sql;
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

**Option 1**

```
$tmp = implode(',', $data);
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM client_details WHERE dob IN ($tmp)");
```

**Option 2**

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM client_details WHERE dob IN (".implode(',', $data).")");
```

Also, there is a mistake in your `bracket formation`.

It should be `dob IN ({implode(',', $data)}");` [Curly braces should close after the closing parenthesis].

Comment: Severity: Warning

Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed ..showing this error

Comment: Error Number: 1064

Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de ')' Ã  la ligne 1

SELECT * FROM client_details WHERE dob IN () and also this error showing

Comment: 03/03/201504/13/201505/11/201506/08/201509/04/201512/06/201503/08/201606/09/201609/10/201603/01/201703/01/201902/27/202702/29/202003/18/201504/28/201505/26/201506/23/201509/19/201512/21/2

Comment: $data values are this

Comment: Try removing `{ }` from your initial query. And what is the datatype of your `dob` column?

Comment: varchar is my datatype

Comment: And is `$data` an array of strings?

Comment: Error Number: 1064

Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '' Ã  la ligne 1

SELECT * FROM client_details WHERE dob IN (implode(',', 03/03/2015)  showing the same error

Comment: $data is an array of strings

Comment: See my edited answer. Try the second option. And also a `)` was missing in the first option. So it may also work now.

Comment: @PrerakSola Your first answer is (almost) right, but your second answer has a small error right at the end. I say 'almost' because dates also need to be enclosed in inverted commas (')

Comment: Oh yes... Forgot the `"`. Thanks for the notification @Strawberry ... :)

Comment: @Strawberry: The datatype of `dob` is `varchar`. So it should work without the  `'`.

Comment: Ah - I see what you're saying.

Comment: I was also not sure about it, but when i tested it, it worked.. !!

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion and also Error Number: 1064

Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '' Ã  la ligne 1

SELECT * FROM client_details WHERE dob IN ({implode(',', Array)} this error showing

Comment: @Fiona: try the second one